# Java Biginteger xor encrypt/decrypt for PHP

Tags: php, biginteger

I'm new to PHP, now I just want to translate java xor encrypt/decrypt code to PHP, which is used for transactions between server and client.
Below is the Java xor code:

```
public static String encrypt(String password, String key) {
    if (password == null)
        return "";
    if (password.length() == 0)
        return "";

    BigInteger bi_passwd = new BigInteger(password.getBytes());

    BigInteger bi_r0 = new BigInteger(key);
    BigInteger bi_r1 = bi_r0.xor(bi_passwd);

    return bi_r1.toString(16);
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String key) {
    if (encrypted == null)
        return "";
    if (encrypted.length() == 0)
        return "";

    BigInteger bi_confuse = new BigInteger(key);

    try {
        BigInteger bi_r1 = new BigInteger(encrypted, 16);
        BigInteger bi_r0 = bi_r1.xor(bi_confuse);

        return new String(bi_r0.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I've did some research and found some info in http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/math.html but can't get it work. My PHP version in the server is 5.4.36. Do I need to install something or perform some configuration?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's the problem with the code? Is it not working? Did you get any error messages? Please be as specific as possible as that will lead to better answers.

Comment: I removed "solved" from the question's title. You can either post your own answer or delete the question. There's no need to modify the question's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it worked. Below is the PHP code

```
function encrypt($string, $key)
{
    $bi_passwd = new Math_BigInteger($string, 256);
    $bi_r0 = new Math_BigInteger($key);
    $bi_r1 = $bi_r0->bitwise_xor($bi_passwd);
    return $bi_r1->toHex();
}

function decrypt($string, $key)
{
    $bi_confuse = new Math_BigInteger($key);
    $bi_r1 = new Math_BigInteger($string, 16);
    $bi_r0 = $bi_r1->bitwise_xor($bi_confuse);
    return $bi_r0->toBytes();
}
```